# How to have a message box pop up only once in a loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, popup, messagebox

I have this small method that pops up a message box warning , problem is that it pops up 3 message box instead of one!
I've tried several ways to counter this issue (including the bool variables in the code and using Distinct in the sql query , though the database doesn't contain any repeatable rows).

The idea is to have the messagebox pop up once for each row that violates my if condition and not 3 times for each row.
So , why is this message box pops up 3 times instead of once? and how to fix it?

```
    void msds_update()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "server=(local);database=PhilipsMaterials;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    con.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string sql = "Select * from [PhilipsMaterials].[dbo].[Materials]";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
    da.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    DateTime longupdate;
    DateTime shortupdate;
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        longupdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Long MSDS Update"]);
        shortupdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["Short MSDS Update"]);
        TimeSpan longsince = DateTime.Now.Subtract(longupdate);
        int longyears = (int)(longsince.Days / 365.25);
        TimeSpan shortsince = DateTime.Now.Subtract(shortupdate);
        int shortyears = (int)(shortsince.Days / 365.25);
        bool flag = false ;
        bool shown = false;
        if (longyears > 4.5) { flag = true; }
        if (flag && !shown)
        {
            string longmsdsname = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Name"]);
            string msg = "Long Msds " + longmsdsname + " must be updated";
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
            shown = true;
        }
        flag = false;
        shown = false;
        if (shortyears > 4.5) { flag = true; }
        if (flag && !shown)
        {
            string shortmsdsname = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["Name"]);
            string msg = "Short Msds " + shortmsdsname + " must be updated";
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
            shown = true;
        }
    } 
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show a single message box with all the message text combined? Or do you want to show the first message box and then exit this loop ?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer. i want to show only one messagebox (or prehaps 2 , if both if conditions holds) for each row. right now i get 3 messagebox with the same text for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values used to perform the if tests and to build the error message always are the values from the row at index zero, you should use the current row indexer used in the foreach loop

Also, do not react immediatly to the error condition, instead build up an error message, wait to end one loop and show the message only if there is an error. No need to use and keep updated two status variables.

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   int rowCounter = 0;
   foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
        rowCounter++;

        longupdate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Long MSDS Update"]);
        shortupdate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Short MSDS Update"]);
        TimeSpan longsince = DateTime.Now.Subtract(longupdate);
        int longyears = (int)(longsince.Days / 365.25);
        TimeSpan shortsince = DateTime.Now.Subtract(shortupdate);
        int shortyears = (int)(shortsince.Days / 365.25);
        if (longyears <= 4.5) 
        {
            string longmsdsname = Convert.ToString(row["Name"]);
            sb.AppendFormat("Long Msds {0}  must be updated\r\n", longmsdsname);
        }
        if (shortyears <= 4.5)
        {
            string shortmsdsname = Convert.ToString(row["Name"]);
            sb.AppendFormat("Short Msds {0}  must be updated\r\n", shortmsdsname);
        }

        // If we have errors, show them and reset the builder for the next loop
        if(sb.Length > 0)
        {
             string msg = string.Format("Error in row {0}\r\n{1}", 
                                         rowCounter.ToString(), sb.ToString());
             MessageBox.Show(msg);
             sb.Length = 0;
        }
    }
```

In this way you have just one message for each wrong row also if there are 2 or more wrong values.

Comment: Tried it but it still shows 3 messagebox messages instead of one per violation.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question correctly then. You have N rows and you loop on them. Inside one loop, you check the values in two fields for the current loop row. If one or both fields contains wrong data ( <= 4.5 ) you need to show ONE message for that row. If this is correct the code above should output a message only if a row contains wrong data. I have updated the answer adding a counter for the current wrong row

Comment: Got it. You don't use the current row in your message, but always row[0]. Changing the answer now

Answer (score 0):

You set the variable shown to false before the if statement, move shown outside of the for-loop.

Comment: I'm sorry , i should have been clearer. I want the messagebox to be shown once for each row the violates my condition. right now it shows up 3 times for each row that holds to the if condition.

Comment: In that case, Daniel's answer works. Initialize your shown flag at the top of the loop and do not reset it to false within the loop. Once set for a message box, it will not show the others anyway.

Comment: My problem is that the same message box with the same text in it is displayed 3 times instead of one. for example: if i had two message box notification but with different texts that would be fine but i don't want the same message to appear 3 times (and i have no idea why it would).

Answer (score 0):

use "break;" after your messagebox. Your program will come out of the loop.

Comment: I don't want to break the loop , i want to have 1 message box notification for each row that violates my condition.